# Display different messages in grid view for not having bound data and no results retrieved

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET `GridView` which I want to populate with a message "No results found" when there are no results to be displayed. Initially I do not want to bind data and have the grid view display "You still need to search".

Using an `EmptyDataTemplate` and just binding `null` to the grid view only displays one type of message. Is there a way to accomplish that the initial message is as above and a different message is displayed when searched and no results are bound to the `GridView`?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the data going to be filled afterwards? With a page refresh and rerendering the grid or with AJAX and filling the grid with JavaScript?

Comment: Rerendering the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really ugly but it might be what you need.

Assuming you have a Label control with the ID `LabelNoData` in the EmptyDataTemplate:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Temp = GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("LabelNoData") as Label;

    if (GridView1.DataSource == null)
        Temp.Text = "Please do a search";
    else
        Temp.Text = "No data found!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. Why use `GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("LabelNoData")` and not the `Label` itself? Is this not possible?